# Is it possible to exit from a main method without terminating the program?

Tags: java, return, program-entry-point, exit

I know about the return statement and have tried it. System.exit(0) also does the same. But using it here terminates the program. Is there any way i can use so that if the user types other input except 1-7 , the program doesn't terminate , so that i don't have to recompile and rerun the program ? Or is it not possible in Java ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewShoppingCart{
public static void main(String args[]) {

    boolean flag = true;
    long code;
    String choice;
    NewShop aShop = new NewShop();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer parse = 0;

    System.out.println("-----ITEM------");
    do {
        System.out.println("1. Display all items");
        System.out.println("2. Search items");
        System.out.println("3. Add items to list");
        System.out.println("4. Add items to cart");
        System.out.println("5. Display cart");
        System.out.println("6. Issue item");
        System.out.println("7. Exit");
        System.out.println("Choice:");
        choice = sc.nextLine();

        try{
         parse = Integer.parseInt(choice);
          }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer"); 
            return;  
        }
        if (parse >=1 && parse <= 7 )
         {

        switch (parse) {

        case 1:
            aShop.display();
            break;

        case 2:
            aShop.searchItem();
            break;

        case 3:
            aShop.addItem();
            break;

        case 4:
            aShop.addItemtoCart();
            break;


        case 5:
            aShop.displayCart();
            break;

        case 6:
            aShop.issueItem();
            break;

        case 7:
            System.out.println("Thank you!\n");
            flag = false;
            break;

        default :
             System.out.println("Please enter choice relevant to context");
          }
        }
     else   return;
       }

     while (flag != false);
    sc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: nop, that is the main entrance of the application... once you return of that method the app is gone!

Comment: just log the exception don't return from there then your while loop will continue and ask for input once more

Comment: You don't need to recompile the program when it terminates. Unless the program deletes itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never go out of `main` with just one thread. This is likely an XY problem. What you really want is to go back to the start of the loop if the user inputs something invalid.

The `continue` keyword will stop executing the current iteration of the enclosing loop and start a new iteration immediately. This is what you should use in place of `return`.

```
    try{
     parse = Integer.parseInt(choice);
      }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer"); 
        return;  // <--- change this to "continue;"
    }
```

Also, this:

```
if (parse >=1 && parse <= 7 )
    {

        switch (parse) {

            case 1:
                aShop.display();
                break;

            case 2:
                aShop.searchItem();
                break;

            case 3:
                aShop.addItem();
                break;

            case 4:
                aShop.addItemtoCart();
                break;


            case 5:
                aShop.displayCart();
                break;

            case 6:
                aShop.issueItem();
                break;

            case 7:
                System.out.println("Thank you!\n");
                flag = false;
                break;

            default :
                System.out.println("Please enter choice relevant to context");
        }
    }
    else return;
```

should really be:

```
    if (parse >=1 && parse <= 7 )
    {

        switch (parse) {

            case 1:
                aShop.display();
                break;

            case 2:
                aShop.searchItem();
                break;

            case 3:
                aShop.addItem();
                break;

            case 4:
                aShop.addItemtoCart();
                break;


            case 5:
                aShop.displayCart();
                break;

            case 6:
                aShop.issueItem();
                break;

            case 7:
                System.out.println("Thank you!\n");
                flag = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter choice relevant to context");
        continue;
    }
```

The "Please enter choice relevant to context" message should really be printed in the else statement. Because in your if, you already checked whether `parse` is between 1 and 7, so in the switch, `parse` can't be anything else so the `default` branch is never reached. After you print the message, you `continue;` in order to go back to the start of the loop.

Comment: default :
                 System.out.println("\n");
              }
            }
            else  System.out.println("Please enter choice between 1 to 7");
              continue;
           }                                                                                                  I think this will do. Because i have been adviced to use default case for the sake of "good practices".

Comment: You can remove the default case because in this case, it will never be reached. The if statement already checks for values outside 1-7. @SHACHINDRATRIPATHI other times having a default case is better because it is easier to know if something does not match all the cases you specified. This can help in debugging.

Comment: @SHACHINDRATRIPATHI If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!

Comment: Check Made ! Thankyou .

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer"); 
            return;  
        }
```

to

```
catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer"); 
            continue;  
        }
```

also in your else block have `continue` instead of `return`.

Comment: You may want to explain how this helps (which I agree it does)